# Can anyone identify this fishing-related tackle/object?

Tags: fishing, fishing-tackle

I've searched whatever I can on the Web, including doing reverse image searches, but unable to identify this... thing?

It's like a screw-together weight, with two plastic washers forming almost a yo-yo like contraption. For the size, it feels quite heavy and it was found while beach detecting in some seaweed washed ashore.

[image: disassembled]

Size wise, it is just short of 7cm long and roughly 2.5cm diameter.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Edit: working out its density, it comes in at ~6.14g/cm3 which makes me sure this is vanadium. If that helps?

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that you could determine the density to three sig figs of precision, or that you could reliably determine what it's made of based on the density. There are hundreds and hundreds of metallic alloys out there, each with its own density. AFAIK vanadium is not used in pure form to make machine parts.

Comment: I simply had a quick search on how to determine density of a cylindrical object, mass (g) / pi*r^2*length, then compared that to the reference table. Trying to help in giving any details in working out what this thing is. Thanks! =)

Comment: Vanadium of 95% purity costs about $20 / pound, so it is very unlikely to be used as a fishing weight. Your weight is nearly a half pound. Perhaps it is a home made contraption. Vanadium steel is used for fishing hooks, but weights are often made of lead.

Comment: @DeeKayy90: These weights have taps and grooves machined into them, so you're not going to get this kind of super-precise estimate of the density just by using a formula for the volume of a cylinder. With the lower volume, you'd have a higher density. Probably these are just steel weights.

Comment: +1s to you both, these comments have been super helpful - I am under the belief it is steel, but those numbers threw me off haha. Its weird that the inside has the two plastic washers and there is a plastic sheath around the thread between the washers, which essentially allow it to "yo-yo". It seems to me to be a higher quality home-made contraption (given the turning) but I am so unsure why the "mechanism" on what is essentially just a weight.

Comment: Okay so, I've figured it out. And the answer was staring me in the face. It looks like this is home-brewed from - get this - a glass screen door handle, akin to what you may have on a shower glass door. And the reason I say staring me in the face? I literally have the same one on my screens. D'oh!

Comment: Are you certain it is fishing tackle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your [Can anyone identify this fishing-related tackle/object?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/27110/can-anyone-identify-this-fishing-related-tackle-object/27596?noredirect=1#comment67286_27110) comment, it looks like you found your answer.  To push it off the Unanswered questions page, I copied it here:

> Okay so, I've figured it out. And the answer was staring me in the face. It looks like this is home-brewed from - get this - a glass screen door handle, akin to what you may have on a shower glass door. And the reason I say staring me in the face? I literally have the same one on my screens. D'oh! - DeeKayy90 May 18 at 4:13

Comment: Posting this as an answer is helpful, as it answers the question. The user does not claim it as his own and gives his source. And it is also acceptable across the Stack Exchange sites.